# SQL Server 2005 view & subquery performance issues

Tags: performance, sql-server-2005

I have the following two tables:

**Person** - approx 7000 rows

- PerosnId - 9 Characters
- PersonType   - Char (one of 'F' / 'C' / 'M')

**PersonStatuses** - approx 90K rows (roughly 13 rows for each Person row)

- Id        - Identity
- PersonId      - 9 character
- StatusCode    - integer
- LastUpdateDate  - DateTime

i'm using a View to return the latest row from PersonStatuses realting to a unique Person row:

**LatestPersonStatuses**

```
SELECT      PersonId, StatusCode 
FROM        PersonStatuses ps1
WHERE       LastUpdateDate = (SELECT MAX(LastUpdateDate) 
                                  FROM   PersonStatuses ps2
                                  WHERE ps2.PersonId = ps1.PersonId)
```

The following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Person.Id
FROM Person  
WHERE  Person.Id  IN (SELECT PersonId 
              FROM LatestPersonStatuses
              WHERE StatusCode = 12) AND
Person.PersonType='F'
```

[image: Plan 1]

takes about a minute to perfrom, thus timing-out, while the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Person.Id
FROM Person  
WHERE  Person.Id  IN (SELECT PersonId 
                     FROM LatestPersonStatuses
                     WHERE StatusCode = 12)
```

performs almost instantly.

[Plan 2 http://tinypic.com/images/404.gif](http://tinypic.com/images/404.gif)

I can't figure out why does the addition of the WHERE clause in the 1st query:

```
Person.PersonType='F'
```

cause such a difference.

Can anybody please direct me?

Comment: Do you have indexes on your tables?

Comment: Sorry to be answering with a question, but... What if you leave out `DISTINCT`? I understand `Id` must be unique to `Person`.

Comment: Hey, dropping the DISTINCT was the first thing i've tried, but seems it has not affect on the complexity. What indexes would you recommend to create? i tried setting one over the PersonType in the Person Table, and one over StatusCode in the PersonStatuses table, but with no change.

Comment: How many results does the query return? What do the execution plans look like? I wonder if the second plan is basically the same as the first one except it has to do a load of bookmark lookups in order to retrieve the value of `PersonType` to evaluate the residual predicate.

Comment: The WHERE clause yields in [this execution plan](http://i56.tinypic.com/n4tc9u.png), No WHERE clause yields in [this execution plan](http://i54.tinypic.com/5xjrbp.jpg)

Comment: @Harel - Are these plans the Actual or Estimated? On the Actual plan for the slow query if you mouse over the arrows can you see any big discrepancies for actual vs estimated number of rows? In particular your bad plan is doing an expensive group by on the inside of the nested loops join. From the size of the arrows it looks as though it expects there to be only 1 row returned from the index seek. How many are actually returned? Do you have up-to-date statistics?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the query optimizer has decided that since you are dealing with a column `persontype` directly, it may be faster to use an index on that column (if you had one), or if not then a direct table scan + filter.  This is in comparison to the perceived/estimated cost of evaluating the subquery and doing an IN-list comparison, without knowing the metrics/statistics of the list from the subquery.

Even looking at your query, I would have almost guessed that it is faster to scan and filter on table column rather than going down the subquery, which involves an expansion of a view.

You should be able to rewrite (for 2005+) the view as

```
--VIEW: LatestPersonStatuses
SELECT PersonId, StatusCode 
FROM   (SELECT *, rownum=row_number() over (
                  partition by personID order by LastUpdateDate desc)
        from PersonStatuses p) X
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Maybe that will help the optimizer

Comment: Hey, problem solved easily by adding an index on the source table of the view, PersonStatuses, on the PersonId column. Somehow missed the fact it had no index, therefore all lookups were inefficient.